# TL-WL8200ND V1 doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, tp-link

I have a TP-Link USB Wireless Adapter model TL-WL8200ND (V1). I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it recognizes the adapater but doesn't connect to any network. It keeps trying to connect but never achieves it.

I looked up some information using Google and this AskUbuntu before but didn't find any way to solve it. Another user tried to help me solve it in Ubuntu 19.04 but it didn't work and I decided to go back to 18.04 (since is LTS and older, I assume it will be easier to solve).

run `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b34d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a04 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b35b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:8204 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 12d1:108a Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 2357:0100  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

run `lsmod | grep rtl`

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              73728  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        57344  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                90112  3 rtl8192c_common,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             552960  14 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mac80211              802816  5 iwldvm,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu,rtlwifi,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              667648  4 iwldvm,rtlwifi,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

run `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e wlx` command:

```
[  798.704839] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x11
[  798.735791] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[  798.735870] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[  798.735949] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[  798.738437] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[  798.741959] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[  798.751865] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[  798.759967] rtl8192cu 3-2:1.0 wlx98ded01ba16b: renamed from wlan0
[  798.791325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx98ded01ba16b: link is not ready
[  816.341902] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[  816.356095] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[  816.931947] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx98ded01ba16b: link is not ready
[  817.035311] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx98ded01ba16b: link is not ready
[  829.054916] wlx98ded01ba16b: authenticate with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10
[  829.065698] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 1/3)
[  829.167596] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 2/3)
[  829.271608] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 3/3)
[  829.375701] wlx98ded01ba16b: authentication with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 timed out
[  830.308514] wlx98ded01ba16b: authenticate with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10
[  830.319240] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 1/3)
[  830.420226] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 2/3)
[  830.524247] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 3/3)
[  830.628294] wlx98ded01ba16b: authentication with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 timed out
[  831.962656] wlx98ded01ba16b: authenticate with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10
[  831.973414] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 1/3)
[  832.077051] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 2/3)
[  832.181076] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 3/3)
[  832.285163] wlx98ded01ba16b: authentication with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 timed out
[  834.116835] wlx98ded01ba16b: authenticate with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10
[  834.127689] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 1/3)
[  834.230102] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 2/3)
[  834.334156] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 3/3)
[  834.438208] wlx98ded01ba16b: authentication with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 timed out
[  844.282086] wlx98ded01ba16b: authenticate with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10
[  844.292967] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 1/3)
[  844.395174] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 2/3)
[  844.499234] wlx98ded01ba16b: send auth to 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 (try 3/3)
[  844.603285] wlx98ded01ba16b: authentication with 98:6b:3d:7b:08:10 timed out
[  854.640825] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx98ded01ba16b: link is not ready
```

run `nmcli dev wifi list`:

```
IN-USE  SSID  MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*       mcca  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  53      ▂▄__  WPA2     

IN-USE  SSID                              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        DIRECT-5C-HP DeskJet 2600 series  Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        mcca                              Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        436802785155                      Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        HOME-95FA                         Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        FABRAY F 2018                     Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        --                                Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        VANESSA DURAN                     Infra  3     195 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        --                                Infra  3     195 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        SANTIAGO                          Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        THE BEATLES                       Infra  9     54 Mbit/s   44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        HERMANOSMOSQUERA                  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        MARTHA GUZMAN                     Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        FAMILIA JIMENEZ                   Infra  8     135 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        --                                Infra  4     195 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        HOME-F2C4                         Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        MOVISTAR_BE30                     Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        MARIO VELASQUEZ                   Infra  3     195 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Sofia                             Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  7       ▂___  WPA2      
        Ingtegral                         Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2      
        MOVISTAR_7EC0                     Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        Penagos.Jamaica                   Infra  2     130 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        ACONDE                            Infra  4     195 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        CLARO_3A60                        Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2      
        MARIA_FLORES                      Infra  7     270 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        --                                Infra  7     195 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2      
        LUIS Q.                           Infra  7     65 Mbit/s   4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        Isabell                           Infra  8     270 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2      
        Iancastro                         Infra  8     54 Mbit/s   4       ____  WPA2      
        .Regalos a tu Puerta              Infra  9     195 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2      
        9F80                              Infra  9     65 Mbit/s   4       ____  WPA2      
        FLIA CUBILLOS CARDON              Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        212202785140                      Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA1 WPA2 
        JENNIFER                          Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  4       ____  WPA2
```

I tried installing a patch from here: https://github.com/0xBADEAFFE/rt8192cu_dkms#uninstall-dkms-driver but the terminal does nothing when I follow the instructions (complete newbie here). I don't understand that much yet but I'm willing to try so if anybody can help me, I'd be forever in your debt.

I'm aware that TP-Link support offers Linux packages for the V2 of this model but I'm V1 and I read before that V2 drivers don't work with it.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a network with WPA1 WPA2? If so, the first thing to try it to change the router's settings to what is recommended: WPA2 only, no mixed modes, and for encryption avoid TKIP.

Comment: Please blacklist rtl8192cu as I suggested in your other question, reboot and show us the settings above again here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link.

Comment: I followed your instructions (now I understood the code part) and well... now my PC does not recognize USB connections. Neither from the WiFi Adapter or others like my Wireless mouse.

Comment: Please post: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`